# curl authentication with ldap credentials

Tags: curl, ldap, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to  connect to servicenow server with curl which uses ldap authentication.

my command:

```
curl -ntlm -u user https://my.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident
```

Then I got:

```
Enter host password for user 'user':
{"error":{"message":"User Not Authenticated","detail":"Required to provide Auth information"},"status":"failure"}
```

How can I get authentication by curl command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this to authenticate:

```
curl -ntlm "https://my.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident" --user 'user':'user_password'
```

Replace with your user Id and password to execute it

Comment: Tried to run the example with additional flag: --header
> curl -ntlm "https://my.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident"  --user 'user':'pass'--header "Accept:application/json"
{"error":{"message":"User Not Authenticated","detail":"Required to provide Auth information"},"status":"failure"} 
but still get the same error

Comment: Did you check if user and pass are valid in Service Now by logging into your instance. Try it out here https://my.service-now.com/login.do

Comment: You are right - I cannot login from  my.service-now.com/login.do  address, but I can login in https://my.service-now.com/sp

Comment: It should work from login.do to access the API. You need to set a back-end password for your ID and then try it. Only SN administrators can do it from the user profile